# Best way to check a range from a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++03

I currently have a `std::map<int,int>`
with values something like this

```
Key Value
60   2
84   3 
99   5
```

Now I always get an int from a method

```
int a = SomeMethod();
```

What I would like to do is check if that number is between a range in the key
so if the number is 45 it is less than key value 60 so I should get back 2. Another example is if the number is 75 more than key vale 60 and less than key value 84 so I should get back 3.
The approach I am currently thinking of is once i have a number. I will iterate through the map until I come across a number that is larger than what i want. If it is I will remove it from the map.Then keep on doing this until I get to a number that fits my condition. I would like to know if there is a better way to approach this ?

Comment: Does your map always have 3 numbers?

Comment: BTW, "no" is not a good way abbreviate "number"

Comment: My map might have 5 numbers

Comment: @MistyD, you might be better off using `vector` and [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Just sayin'

Comment: As per your explanation, you just want to perform 'get' operation. So, why are you thinking to remove elements from the map?

Comment: @InnocentBystander: `vector`'s sound advice if doing many searches without frequent map updates, and memory and/or performance is important, but [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) just tests for membership - this logic needs [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) so there's an iterator to either the matching or the closest element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound). It returns an iterator to the first entry with a key not less than the given argument.

```
int a = SomeMethod();
auto it = myMap.lower_bound(a);
int val = someNotFoundSentinelValue;
if(it != myMap.end()
  val = it->second;
```

Comment: so if i have 84 will it return 3 or 5 ?

Comment: Oops, `upper_bound` returns the entry that is strictly greater, while `lower_bound` is the one for "not less than". Fixed!

Comment: @Pradhan, your example code still says `upper_bound`